# Edit and Continue for web application

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, web

I check edit and continue in Web application properties, still have to stop the debugger!!, re-attach to the project.

If Web application cannot be edited while debugger is attached is there an easy way to convert it to web site, given that the application is on live server, and I am newly introduced to it.

What do u think?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you just need to 'pause' the debugger rather than stop it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10838410/2034089

Answer (score 0):

edit and continue for me worked just in forms, console etc applications