# Edit and Continue is not working in VS2010 even for 32bit

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have looked at all these but I have not as yet found an answer.
Now that time has moved on is there a solution to this?

Test win form target 3.5 or 4 net.
Win7 Ultimate 64 bit.
Project set to 32 bit as advised.
No fancy code or linked projects or dlls just a standard test project with no code.

I run the form than open the cs code for the form and press CR to add a comment.
I then get the error message...

Edit and Continue
Changes are not allowed while code is running or if the option 'Break all processes when one process breaks' is disabled. The option can be enabled in Tools, Options, Debugging.

Comment: Have you verified the setting it points you to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding was always that 'Edit and Continue' wouldn't allow you to edit code while your application is 'running'....

You need to pause your code; then you can 'continue'.

If your form is running and you want to add a comment to the .CS code - you need to either have your code hit a break-point first or manually pause your code (cntrl+alt+break - or available in Debug / Break All)

I seem to have the best luck with edit and continue when modifying code at or near the execution point.  I'm sure someone can give a technical reason for this, but I don't know it off the top of my head.

(my apologies if you *are* doing this and I just misread your question)

Comment: Wow, I have been assuming that because I'm running in debug mode I could just edit. But you are correct if I set a break point or manually pause code Edit and Continue works. Thanks.